# Android hdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi. Provide drawables for only single directory?

Tags: android, android-resources

Android has the concept of several density buckets for handling screens with different resolution display. We all know that.

I am used to providing images for each bucket but there also exists practice of having *some* images only for a single bucket, say, `xxhdpi` - Android would scale it down as required.

I would like to know the practical advice for doing something like this. For example, if we were to categorize the images, we would probably have something like,

- App launcher icon(mipmap by default)
- Other icons
- Medium graphics with less details and/or size
- Heavy/detailed graphics, usually heavy in size as well

So, what would be the advice for icons - is it advisable to provide only xxxhdpi for them?

The same can be asked for each of the category.

As a side note, I checked out the resources with WhatsApp APK and they seem to have several of their images for only a single bracket - xxhdpi.

I am sure every developer follows some strategy for the resources. Any pointers or industry experience is appreciated.

Comment: Curious what you ended up going with on the dpi folders? Seems to be no sufficient answer as to the downside of just going with one or two folders for the icons. We have been having a bit of internal discussion about this in our company and looking to get a full understanding.

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking to add **png or webp** type of image file then, you need to add different images based on their size in different folders such as **xhdpi, mdpi, xxhdpi** etc. **If you do not add than the device will not automatically scale down images but use the image which you have added and near to device density**. Another approach is, you can **use drawable-vector images** than it is okay that you only create one file which is XML, the mobile phone will automatically render this drawable type of file based on screen size. **If you want to use images for icons than it is my suggestion to use vector drawable image always instead of different png files.** This is my experience that, during one project execution, I have observed that for low memory devices the app gets crashed when using png and webp files, but when used vector graphics file instead of png/webp, it doesn't crash and work faster also benefits in application size. So, this is my personal opinion may be different people have different views.

**Note:** there are many online tools available which can convert png to svg image which can be imported to the android studio as drawable using vector assets, which is very helpful